# Phantom js page automation

Tags: phantomjs

Всем привет, пытаюсь на фантоме переходить по ссылкам, но не удаётся, имел кто опыт работы с ним? Кнопка почему-то не нажимается.

```
//index.php
shell_exec('C:\bin\phantomjs.exe /script.js https://ya.ru/');

//script.js
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
url = system.args[1];
page.open(url, function (status) {
page.injectJs('/jquery.js');    //подключаем jquery.js
page.evaluate(function() {      
    $(".input__control").val('Phantom');
    $(".button").click();

});
page.render('example.png');
phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Использовал CasperJS

```
casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start();
casper.open('http://ya.ru');
casper.then(function doSomething() {
this.page.injectJs('jquery.js');
var items = this.evaluate(function () {
    $(".input__control").val('Phantom');
    $(".button").click();
    //search2

});

});
casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
document.querySelector('.search2').submit();
});
casper.then(function(){
this.capture("temp.png");
});
casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, JQuery не подключилась. Смущает слэш перед `jquery.js`. Делай проверку `if(page.injectJs(...)) {...}`. Да и неплохо бы проверять `status` на `'success'` на случай, если страница вообще не загрузится.

Comment: Я изменил поле ввода, значит jquery подключилась,и запрос проходит, т.к. команда render показывает что просто ввели в поле значение и всё.

Comment: Тогда копай код на jQuery. Лучше сначала проверить в браузере на живой странице

Comment: Попробуйте зайти на ya.ru и в консоль ввести

$(".input__control").val('Phantom');
$(".button").click();

вроде работает, но фантом не хочет это делать.

Comment: Пробуй другие способы: .trigger('click'), без использования jQuery, form.submit, вызовом события click через addEventListener и т.д.